# Error durante el uso de npm - ERR! code ECONNRESET

Tags: nodejs, npm, windows11

Les expongo este problema porque he buscado muchas soluciones y ninguna ha funcionado. Soy cubano (no se si esto influye por el acceso IP), estoy usando mi laptop en mi red domestica sin proxy ni VPN, e intento crear una app de React usando `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`. Resulta que esta petición me está dando el siguiente error: (tambien me da ese error al intentar `npm i -g npm@latest`)

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\leona\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-13T16_21_40_416Z-debug-0.log
```

Buscando información al respecto he llegado a probar varias soluciones:

- Limpiar cache usando `npm cache clear --force`
- Verificar y eliminar la configuracion de algun proxy que por casualidad ha sido configurado (`npm config get proxy` y `https-proxy` , `npm config delete proxy` y `https-proxy`, así como `npm config rm proxy` y `https-proxy`)
- Le he cambiado la web de registro para que no funcione con SSL `npm config get registry http://registry.npmjs.org`
- He desactivado el antivirus y firewall

También he realizado algunas pruebas de red abriendo https://registry.npmjs.org/ desde el navegador y noto algo interesante. Cuando intento abrir me da error `ECONNRESET` pero luego de actualizar varias veces me deja acceder por un tiempo, al rato vuelvo a intentar y nuevamente me da ese error hasta que me permite acceder de nuevo.

Hago `ping registry.npmjs.org` y sin embargo a la primera funciona sin problemas. Evidentemente el problema es de red, pero hasta esta fecha son casi 4 días buscando soluciones y no he podido solucionar.

Datos que pudieran servir:

```
Node v19.2.0
Npm v8.19.3
SO Windows 11 x64
Device Laptop Lenovo ThinkPad
```

Agradecería toda la ayuda posible !!!!

Comment: En mi caso, fue durante el trabajo que tuve el mismo error. Intente con todos los métodos que se expusieron en la web pero no funciono. Tuve que bajar por un momento mi antivirus en este caso fue kaspersky y finalmente pude crear el proyecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eso sucede por dos cosas.
1- Debes tener la velocidad de internet muy lenta (sabes como es nauta). Entonces te recomiendo que revises si hay alguna actualización corriendo, o tu laptop esta descargando algo que pone la conexión mas lenta.

2- Debido a que los últimos tags los vinculan con ciertos cdn, a veces están bloqueados por IP para Cuba, entonces te recomiendo que uses un vpn (yo uso windscribe) y así puedes saltarte el bloqueo de IP.

Sugerencia

Comment: Michas gracias, realmente la solución estaba en usar un VPN 

Answer (score 0):

Mano me estaba pasando e hice algunas pruebas, es un error de conexion debido a que la pagina se encuentra cerrada para cuba. Te recomiendo una VPN

Comment: Saludos, gracias por el aporte aunque la pregunta ya tenia una respuesta correctamente respondida. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Yo estoy en la misma situación, también soy cubano, si encuentro una
> solución les comento.

**Como les prometí les comento la respuesta**
La solución que me funcionó fue instalar un VPN, al parecer estos recursos están bloqueados para el territorio Cubano, no tenía que ver con la velocidad de conexión, al menos no en mi caso, igual es bueno reintentar varias beses si la conexión esta mala, pero si la barra de progreso no se mueve nada, ponle el cuño, necesitas instalar un VPN.